# Are there routers that dynamically use both 2.4 and 5 GHz for connected clients?

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router, dual-band

Are there routers that dynamically use both 2.4 and 5 GHz for connected clients, that is, rather than having a client pick one or the other frequency band, allow a client to connect to both and dynamically switch from one band to another as conditions dictate?  For example, if a router offers a 2.4, and 5, and a generic connection point, is the generic connection point using both bands?

What if any brands/models of routers offer this capability?

Comment: As far as I know, this doesn't exist. A router just gives out the freqencies and its up to the client to connect to one or the other.

Comment: That would only be possible with a dual-band wireless card in the client machine, one that only accepts 2.4 and one (at the same time) accepts 5ghz. It would not be a function of the router. You could have a pair of wireless cards with those separate frequencies to do that if you really wished to.

Comment: The routers exist that already broadcast at both ranges, so the client would be the key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, all simultaneous dual-band APs (access points, a.k.a. wireless routers) can do this. Just make sure to set the same network name (SSID), security type (e.g. WPA2 Personal) and pass phrase for both bands.

By the way, the IEEE 802.11 standard leaves the band selection up to the client. When there are multiple APs publishing the same SSID, the client chooses which AP to join, and when to roam to another. A simultaneous dual band (a.k.a. "dual-band concurrent") AP is technically two APs in the same box. The client can choose whether it joins the 2.4 GHz instance or the 5GHz instance, and the client chooses when to roam from one to the other as conditions change.

Many enterprise-class APs have "band-steering" features that try to second-guess their clients' band choices, and try to trick the clients into picking bands differently than the clients normally would. I'm sure those vendors will tell you these features are great and necessary, but I'm skeptical of the whole approach.